# Why does a THREE.js gilt clone in another renderer slow down frame rate?

Tags: three.js, cloning, gltf

I have a gltf-scene added to my main render:

```
loader.load( 'models/model.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    ...
    scenes['game'].add( gltf.scene );
}
```

This works fine and I'm able to make clones without any issues:

```
loader.load( 'models/model.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    ...
    scenes['game'].add( gltf.scene );
    var myClone = gltf.scene.clone();
    scenes['game'].add( myClone );
}
```

But when I try to add the clone to a second renderer things start to get tricky:

```
loader.load( 'models/model.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
    ...
    scenes['game'].add( gltf.scene );
    var myClone = gltf.scene.clone();
    scenes['inventory'].add( myClone );
}
```

The frame rate drops dramatically when both gilt scenes are within camera view on both renderers. I checked both objects and the seem unique in every way.
Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Having two renderers is very poor practice, performance-wise. It generates two WebGL contexts, consumes a lot more memory, and essentially negates any efficiencies that the GPU might want to implement. You can have multiple scenes, and multiple cameras, but don't use multiple renderers. You should share one renderer instead, with something like this:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var scene1 = new THREE.Scene();
var scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
var cam1 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
var cam2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();

update() {
    renderer.render(scene1, cam1);
    renderer.render(scene2, cam2);
}
```